# Rules for naming fractions with non-trivial denominators

Tags: technical-terminology, mathematics

My son asks me and I've realized that I have no idea - I've never managed to use this layer of vocabulary since I've never been taught in German school.

So, when it comes to fractions there's a clear pattern of naming for degrees of ten, that is: ein Zehntel, ein Hundertstel, ein Tausendstel etc.

However, when it comes to less trivial fractions I have no idea how it's to be correctly said in German. For instance, how exactly I'm supposed to say 1/102? Ein hundertundzweitens or what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually you will add the suffix

> -tel
>
> -stel if the number ends with 'g' or 'd' (zwanzig, dreißig, tausend, etc.)
>
> -el if the number ends with 't' (acht, dreihundertacht, etc.)

but no rule without exceptions

> 1/1 ein Eintel / ein Ganzes<sup>1</sup>   (not ein einstel - for the sake of completeness)
>
> 1/2 ein Halb (not ein Zweitel)
>
> 1/3 ein Drittel (not ein Dreitel)
>
> 1/4 ein Viertel (the pattern starts here)
>
> 1/5 ein Fünftel
>
> 1/6 ein Sechstel
>
> 1/7 ein Siebtel (in some regions: ein Siebentel<sup>2</sup>)
>
> 1/8 ein Achtel (not ein Achttel)
>
> 1/9 ein Neuntel
>
> 1/10 ein Zehntel
>
> etc (I don't think there are any more exceptions<sup>3</sup>  )

It is the same for larger numbers. Get the number in German and add a "-tel", "el" or "-stel"

> 102 - einhundertundzwei / einhundertzwei -> 102 - ein Einhundertundzweitel / ein Einhundertzweitel
>
> 120 - einhundertzwanzig -> 1/120 - ein Einhundertzwanzigstel
>
> 408 - vierhundertacht -> ein Vierhundertachtel
>
> 1234 - eintausendzweihundertvierunddreißig -> 1/1234 - ein Eintausendzweihundertvierunddreißigstel
>
> 217 - zweihundertsiebzehn - 1/217 - ein Zweihundertsiebzehntel

If you are unsure how to write a number in German take a look at [this tool](http://www.calculino.com/de/umrechnungen/zahlen-in-worten_rechner.html)

**Edit: In addition**

<sup>1</sup> As @fNek said in the comments 1/1 is referred to as "ein Ganzes" (pl. "Ganze", lit. "whole thing"), while 4/1 (vier Eintel) is called "vier Ganze", 5/1 (fünf Eintel) "fünf Ganze" etc.

<sup>2</sup> As @VolkerLandgraf mentioned in the comments there are some regions in the German-speaking area in which "siebentel" is used. Mostly in middle eastern Germany and eastern/south eastern Austria. Take a look at [this website](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Siebentel_/_Siebtel) for more details. Nevertheless "siebtel" is the dominant term.

<sup>3</sup> When referring to denominators that are greater than 100 and the last two digits are 01, 03 or 07 the single-digit 'rules' [are often used](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2009/03/02/hundertdrei-im-nenner/).

> 1/101 - ein Einhunderteintel
>
> 1/103 - ein Einhundertdrittel
>
> 1/107 - ein Einhundertsiebtel

Comment: In the 19th century *Dritteil* was used instead of *Drittel*, for an example see [here](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20001107232).

Comment: "Eintel" is also often referred to as "Ganzes" (pl. "Ganze", lit. "whole thing")

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question about 1/102. With your rule would you say it is "Einhundertundzweitel"? That doesn't sound right to me...

Comment: @user2705196 I was off by 1 ^^ . Thanks, I added the 1/102. It sounds odd, but well ... that's the way it is. Einhundertundzweitel / Einhundertzweitel

Comment: @infinitezero I'm really sure it's correct like that. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Eintel) defines it as "Nenner eines oder mehrerer Ganzen, die als gemeiner Bruch geschrieben sind".

Comment: “Einhundert″ bothers me slightly. It sounds like you’re trying too hard. Just say “hundert”. Could this be a regional thing?

Comment: @besc einhundert and hundert are synonymous. You are right, it is more economical to write it like this, but I chose the "long" variant because I think that it shows the structure of German numerals better (einhundert, zweihundert, etc.).

Comment: @infinitezero Never heard "aufleiten" ^^. I made some (hopefully) last fixes that we both can probably live with ^^.

Comment: Pupils use it all the time, because "aufleiten" is the logical opposite to "ableiten". Anyway, I can live with your recent edit. +1

Comment: I’ll point out that in the context of mathematics (for example in a maths class at school) I would prefer *Eintel* over *Ganzes*. This does not apply to everyday life.

Comment: Bei 1/7 muss ich Dir widersprechen: Die normale Form ist tatsächlich *siebentel*. Das *siebtel* ist ursprünglich eine regional auftretende umgangssprachliche Verkürzung, die in letzter Zeit allerdings so weite Verbreitung gefunden hat, dass sie mittlerweile auch in der Schriftform akzeptiert zu sein scheint.